# AOS and .attr() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, aos.js

```
    AOS.init();
$('.content').attr({
  'data-Aos': 'fade-up'
});
```

The code works in a way that the element disappears.
Why does that happen?

Comment: Without seeing a more complete code example including the relevant HTML and CSS, or better still a working example of the problem, we can't help you debug this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please do take the time to fully read the [tour] and [ask].   In your case, we need a little more to go on, ideally enough code to reproduce the issue.  Please also see [mcve].

Comment: Possibly related: https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm sorry. I actually created a distribution page, but now I put down the address for a while because I made a temporary plan. For now, the attribute is applied inline. https://rkde8938.github.io/takem1/

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you for your kind guidance. Can I use this? I applied it inline. rkde8938.github.io/takem1